# Win32 - How to add slider in toolbar?

Tags: c++, winapi

Win32/C++
Hi i created toolbar with few buttons:

```
TBBUTTON tbb[3];
TBADDBITMAP tbab;
tbab.hInst = HINST_COMMCTRL;
tbab.nID = IDB_STD_SMALL_COLOR;
SendMessage(hTool, TB_ADDBITMAP, 0, (LPARAM)&tbab);
ZeroMemory(tbb, sizeof(tbb));
tbb[0].iBitmap = STD_FILENEW;
tbb[0].fsState = TBSTATE_ENABLED;
tbb[0].fsStyle = TBSTYLE_BUTTON;
tbb[0].idCommand = ID_LAYER_1;

tbb[1].iBitmap = STD_FILEOPEN;
tbb[1].fsState = TBSTATE_ENABLED;
tbb[1].fsStyle = TBSTYLE_BUTTON;
tbb[1].idCommand = ID_LAYER_2;

tbb[2].iBitmap = STD_FILESAVE;
tbb[2].fsState = TBSTATE_ENABLED;
tbb[2].fsStyle = TBSTYLE_BUTTON;
tbb[2].idCommand = ID_LAYER_3;

hTool = GetDlgItem(hWnd, IDC_MAIN_TOOL);

hTool = CreateWindowEx(0, TOOLBARCLASSNAME, NULL, WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE, 0, 0, 0, 0, hWnd, (HMENU)IDC_MAIN_TOOL, GetModuleHandle(NULL), NULL);
SendMessage(hTool, TB_BUTTONSTRUCTSIZE, (WPARAM)sizeof(TBBUTTON), 0);   
SendMessage(hTool, TB_ADDBUTTONS, sizeof(tbb)/sizeof(TBBUTTON), (LPARAM)&tbb);
```

and now i want to add trackbar or slider in toolbar? How can i do that? I looked up in msdn for toolbar informations but there is nothing about adding except buttons?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found on msdn:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh298391(v=vs.85).aspx

`toolbar` variable is `HWND` of toolbar!

```
HWND track_bar = CreateWindowEx(NULL, TRACKBAR_CLASS,L"Trackbar", 
                                WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | TBS_AUTOTICKS | TBS_ENABLESELRANGE,
                                80, 0, 200, 40, toolbar, (HMENU)ID_TRACKBAR, hInst, NULL );
```